# how to make my existing application an extendable app using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, plugins, add-in

I have an existing application built in vb.net. What I would like to do is to add some plugins or add-ins to my existing application. How could i do that?

Awaiting for your positive replies..

cheers

Comment: Perhaps what you need is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)?

Comment: what do you mean by that?and how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx). It is pretty cool does not need any external libs because it is part of the .Net Framework. It can detect plugins automatically and it is not so much work to implement it.

The only disadvantage I know is that it is impossible to unload such a plugin. But this is in general a problem with dynamic loaded libaries.

Comment: Do you have any references or tuts on how to use MEF?

Comment: The link points to the MSDN with many examples. If you like I can search also examples on codeproject for you. Like [this great one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/488513/MEF-in-NET-4-5).

Comment: thanks it really helps a lot especially for a beginner like me.this could help me along the road that ill be doing in my project.

Comment: noted, i appreciate it.

Comment: Why I can't add the System.ComponentModel.Composition?

Comment: Which .net version are you using?

Comment: I already figure it out :). I used the 3.5 and now i change it to 4.0. thanks.